# Laravel image being posted to database as "/private/var/tmp/"

Tags: php, image, laravel, upload

I'm trying to store an image in my Laravel project, but I'm having an issue. The image is sucessfuly being added to the `/public/images` folder as its filename, but when the request hits the database, its added as `/private/var/tmp/XXXXX`. I've tried to set $request->file as the name, but it still posts as the `var/temp`.

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        //  'address' => 'required',
        //  'city' => 'required',
        //  'postcode' => 'required',
        //  'restDesc' => 'required',
        //  'telNumb' => 'required',
        //  'resWebsite' => 'required',
        //  'restDesc' => 'required',
        //  'business_id' => 'unique:busprofiles,business_id',
    ];

    $customMessages = ["Message"];

    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $request->file->store('public/uploads');
        $filename = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filesize = $request->file->getClientSize();
        $request->file = $request->file->storeAs('public/uploads', $filename);
    }

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);

    Busprofile::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('business.dashboard')
        ->with('success', 'Profile created successfully');
}
```

If it helps: return `$request->file` returns the correct URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `Busprofile::create($request->all());`. You do indeed get the original filename with `$filename = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();` but your request stays the same.

Create the array for the database entries manually, according to your database needs.

```
$data = ['filename' => $request->file->getClientOriginalName(), 
           ...,
        ];
```

and

```
Busprofile::create($data);
```